# qt.webChannelTransport from sub-frame

Tags: qtwebengine, qtwebchannel

Is it possible to use the qt.webChannelTransport from a sub-frame?  It seems like QWebEnginePage.setWebChannel only creates the qt.webChannelTransport object in the top frame.  I've considered trying to inject scripts to handle  cross document messages and then use the Qt WebChannel between the main frame and the qt application, but that seems like a total pain.